# How to Implement Link List properly in C/C++ without program crashing

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to implement Linked List. In this sample program, user inputs an integer value (the number of strings to store in the list) and then strings one by one... But after several inputs (may be 4 or 5) the program crashes [like the image here...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m65wN.png)

Even, I can't call any function more than 3 times at once which contains malloc() inside them..
I don't know why the problem is occurring. Help me fixing the issue....

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef struct Linked_List NODE;

struct Linked_List
{
    string data;
    NODE* next;
};

//Function prototypes
NODE *traverse(NODE *temp);
NODE* createNode(string data);
void preAppend(NODE* ln_list, string x);
NODE* find_data(NODE* ln_list, string data);

int main()
{
    NODE* x=createNode("");
    int t;
    cin >>t;
    string z;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin >> z;
        preAppend(x, z);
    }

    traverse(x);
    return 0;
}

NODE *traverse(NODE *temp)
{
    cout << temp->data << endl;
    if(temp->next==NULL) return temp;
    traverse(temp->next);
}

NODE* createNode(string data)
{
    NODE* node = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    if(node==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error creating node (Error! Allocating Memory)\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    node->data = data;
    node->next = NULL;
}

void preAppend(NODE* ln_list, string x)
{
    NODE* new_node = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    if(new_node==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! Appending (Error Allocating Memory)\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    new_node->data = x;
    new_node->next = ln_list->next;
    ln_list->next = new_node;
}

NODE* find_data(NODE* ln_list, string data)
{
    NODE* current_node;
    current_node = ln_list;
    while(current_node->next!=NULL)
    {
        if(current_node->data == data)
        {
            return current_node;
        }
        current_node  = current_node -> next ;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your code:

**Usage of `malloc` instead of `new`**

Using `malloc` for objects containing c++ objects (like `string`in your case) won't call the constructors and therefore any operation upon the non constructed objects will fail.

If your program works without the `return` statements, it's because of [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Solution:

Replace

```
NODE* new_node = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
```

with

```
NODE* new_node = new NODE;
```

**No `return` statements in non void functions**

```
NODE *traverse(NODE *temp)
{
  cout << temp->data << endl;
  if (temp->next == NULL) return temp;
  return traverse(temp->next);  // return statement is needed here
}

NODE* createNode(string data)
{
  NODE* node = new NODE;
  if (node == NULL)
  {
    printf("Error creating node (Error! Allocating Memory)\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  node->data = data;
  node->next = NULL;
  return node;    // return statement needed here
}
```

**Abuse of recursion**

Using recursion in `traverse` may result in a stack overflow for long lists.

You should use a iterative approach. But you've found out that one already.

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded the whole code at once. This method should work without any interruption
although if you want a complete understanding of each part i will recommend you to go over this article that i wrote on my website.
https://www.thebytewise.com/post/data-structure-and-algorithm-using-c-linear-linked-list-thebytewise

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void createList();
void traverseList();

struct node{
int data;
struct node *next;
}*header;


int main(){
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    createList(n);
    printf("\nData in the list:\n");
    traverseList(n);
    return 0;
}

void createList(int n){
struct node *newNode, *temp;
int data, i;

newNode = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

if(newNode == NULL){
    printf("ERROR: Memory Overflow");
}
else{
    printf("Enter element 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &data);
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    header = newNode;
    temp = newNode;

    for(i=2;i<=n;++i){

            newNode = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

       if(newNode == NULL){
        printf("ERROR: Memory Overflow");
       }
       else{
        printf("Enter element %d: ",i);
        scanf("%d",&data);

        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        temp->next = newNode;
        temp = temp->next;
       }
    }
}
}

void traverseList(int n){
struct node *temp;
int i;

if(header == NULL){
    printf("ERROR: Memory Underflow");
}

else{
    temp = header;
    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        printf("\ndata %d= %d",i+1, temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
}
```